# Running ghost inside Angular

Tags: angular, reactjs, ghost-blog

Currently I have created an angular application.

I followed the instructions to get ghost up and running from ghost documentation https://docs.ghost.org/docs/using-ghost-as-an-npm-module

But these are running as 2 applications

- ghost (localhost:2368)
- angular application (localhost:4200)

What I want is to run ghost inside my angular application.

This has to be seamlessly integrated as if they are the same site where main app will have good control over it.

I have currently managed to do this with using iframes in components but that doesn't really give much control in the main app.

Is there a way to achieve this without using iframes?

Following shows the angular application with 2 iframes for the home component and admin component of ghost.

[image: angular app with 2 components with iframes]